# Monitoring bad links with RegEx in Google Analytics

Tags: regex, url, google-analytics, filtering

How do I optimize this to find all links ending in weird typos, yet still exclude correct links (ending with .html) from the results?

```
htmll$|hhtml$|httml$|htmml$|htmll$|btml$|hml$|htl$
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could do `h.*t.*m.*l.*$` and then check the length is greater than 4 and then check against `[^h]tml$|h[^t]ml|ht[^m]l|htm[^l]` (if you can check length).

Comment: @MikeH-R Unforunately Google Analytics allows only the basic functions of RegEx, Wildcards .*+?| Anchors ^$ Grouping ()[]-
The solution you wrote does not filter out url's that end with parameters of any kind. I mean, the RegEx I used in question does the work, but I was wondering if I can optimize it for later use and combinations with other criteria I might want to use.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, that's [some pretty restrictive regex rules](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034324?hl=en-GB) but that kinda makes it interesting.
since we have no character negation but we do have character classes we could do:

```
[a-gi-z]tml$|h[a-su-z]ml|ht[a-ln-z]l|htm[a-km-z]
```

for my second suggestion and:

```
h.+tml|ht.+ml|htm.+l|html.+
```

to replace the first option leading to a total of:

```
[a-gi-z]tml$|h[a-su-z]ml|ht[a-ln-z]l|htm[a-km-z]|h.+tml|ht.+ml|htm.+l|html.+
```

EDIT: Having noticed that the .+'s can catch things we don't want this should be changed slightly.

```
(.*[a-gi-z]tml|h.*[a-su-z]ml|ht.*[a-ln-z]l|htm.*[a-km-z])$
```

Comment: I have to admit, I have no idea why it does not work. In GA, I still receive correct URLs after applying this RegEx filter (both links ending with .html and ones with parameters). Yet, in some of the RegEx testers I use the RegEx you wrote catches bad links. Let me give you an upvote for trying, I'll try to find a solution through trial and error.

Comment: that's weird, hang on, I just realised I didn't put in the $ symbol, which could result in you catching some bad links, let me throw up another attempt.

Comment: @Matt try that, if not then good luck with your trial and error. :)